# Stopping Cronic Jobs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the Cronic gem to schedule jobs in my Rails app.

I am stopping Cronic jobs using the command "script/cronic -k -P tmp/pids/cronic.pid" everytime I redeploy the app.

My question is: if a Cronic job is currently running, is it automatically killed? Or does it wait for the job to stop before the entire Cronic process is stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say, but https://github.com/bazaarlabs/dante/blob/master/lib/dante/runner.rb#L211 seems to point that Dante (which Cronic uses to handle deamonization) sends a Process.kill("TERM") to the PID.

Now I think the cronjob process should wait until its finished processing, but it depends on the implementation. If I were you I'd try it out myself. Create a Job that just sleeps for a certain amount of time then send kill  (do not set -9) via unix terminal and see if it exits immediately or not.

Comment: What does TERM do? wait for it to finish?